Group generated by Image of Uniformizer under local Artin Map
Let $L_w/K_v$ be a finite abelian extension of complete non-archim valued local fields and $\Phi: K_v^{\ast} \to Gal(L_w/K_v)$ canon induced from local Artin map (composed with qoution on codomain side) from local Artin map.
Let $\pi_K$ a uniformizer of $K_v$.
And my naive question is what do we know about the subgroup of $Gal(L_w/K_v)$ generated by $\Phi(\pi_K)$ from Galois theoretic viewpoints. It appears pretty "canonical" so seems that it might play a central role. For example, which subfield corresponds to it via Galois correspondence (ie which fixed subfield).
My naive guess is that we get via Galois corresp the maximal unramified extn of $L_w/K_v$, but surprisingly I nowhere found a proof of it (if it is actually true...). Firstly, is my conjecture correct? If yes, does somebody know a source containing the proof?
The image of $\pi_K$ corresp by definition of Artin map to the lift of Frobenius map of underlying residue field extension. So restricted to maximal unramified extension $U_u/K_v$ of $L_w/K_v$ it is actually the Frobenius. But it's not clear to me to which intermediate field it acually corresponds under Galois corresp.

The first thing to note is that the choice of $\pi$ is not canonical, so one should not expect to get a canonical field out of this construction independent of the choice of $\pi$.
One of the properties characterizing the local Artin map is that if $L_w/K_v$ is an finite unramified extension, then $\Phi(\pi)$ is the Frobenius element in $\text{Gal}(L_w/K_v)$. Therefore $\Phi(\pi)$ certainly does not fix $L_w$ if $L_w/K_v$ is unramified nontrivial; in fact, it does the opposite, generating the entire Galois group. The subgroup corresponding to the maximal unramified extension is instead $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_{K_v}^\times)$. That is, $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_{K_v}^\times)$ is the inertia subgroup. The units are precisely the elements whose images under $\Phi$ fix all unramified extensions.
The field fixed by the image of $\pi$ in $\text{Gal}(K_v^{\text{ab}}/K_v)$ under the Artin map, usually denoted $K_{\pi}$, is more complicated to describe. Again, I stress that $K_\pi$ depends on the choice of $\pi$. One standard way to construct it is via Lubin-Tate theory. Some relevant properties are that $K_\pi$ is a totally ramified infinite abelian extension and we have $K_v^{\text{ab}} = K_{\pi}K^{\text{ur}}_v$. I don't know an easy way to compute $K_{\pi} \cap L_w$ (which is the fixed field you are seeking) for a given finite abelian extension $L_w/K_v$.

could you sketch the argument or give a reference where one look up the proof that the maximal unramified extension corresponds precisely to $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_{K_v}^\times)$?

This follows from the property that $\Phi(\pi)$ acts as Frobenius. This is true for all choices of uniformizer. Any given $u \in \mathcal{O}_{K_v}^\times$ can be written as $\pi/\pi'$ for two different choices of uniformizer $\pi, \pi'$, so $\Phi(u)$ must act by $\Phi(\pi)\Phi(\pi')^{-1} = \text{Frob}\cdot \text{Frob}^{-1} = 1$ on any finite unramified extension. Conversely, any non-unit acts nontrivially on $K_v^{\text{ur}}$ since it acts by a nonzero power of Frobenius.
